# How can I execute code after rendering a response to the client in Grails?

Tags: grails

I am writing a controller in Grails 2.X which kicks off a longish job. I would like to be able to render something to the web page which states that the process has started, with the id of the job that is in progress, and have that response actually show up in the user's web browser, and then continue processing on the job.

I have tried just using render without returning, and the user's browser just hangs until the entire job has completed, then renders that the job started.

I tried redirecting to a different action that renders my message, but that also hangs the browser until the job is complete.

I have looked into using filters and the afterInterceptor, but as best as I can tell these take effect and do their processing before the final page is sent back to the client. I need to send my final page back to my client and then continue processing.

Comment: So you need to spin a new thread, but then to get the data to the users, you will have to implement some form of long polling, comet, websockets, etc..

Comment: I may, I was not planning to have a continuous update until finish though. It is more of a 'set it and forget it' type of task. I think I will just persist the status of the job to the DB and provide a controller to check in on it if desired.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to kick off a background job. You can use quartz or look at grails 2.3 async items. If it is pretty long using Quartz is probably your best option.

You will want to return something the client can use to query for the state of the job such as a job id or some record you update once processing is finished.

Comment: I think grails 2.3 asynch might just be the answer to all of my problems! requirements changing as they do, I have been pulled off of this task for today, but I'll mark this as the accepted answer once I prove the concept out.